# how to create urdf?

Tags: gazebo, urdf

When creating urdf.

1.I have a 3D model file, but I do not want to be required to make a large calculation due to collision confirmation when creating a trajectory.

Is this an important issue, and is it therefore possible to create and use a simple link?

2. I want to create a manipulator with a simple link.

At this time,

a) After creating a wheel with the axis  `rpy ="-${pi/2} 0 0"` at the origin, set the axis to `axis=" 0 0 1 "`

b) After leaving the axis as is at the origin, create the wheel as a square and express only the axis as `axis="0 1 0"`

Is there a big difference between the two?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 
The following tutorial may help: 
[Building a Visual Robot Model with URDF from Scratch](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf/Tutorials/Building%20a%20Visual%20Robot%20Model%20with%20URDF%20from%20Scratch)